# Group, QR, QNR, Product of distinct primes

Tags: prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

$N = pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. $ZN^*$ is all $x$ belonging to $ZN$ such that $gcd(x, N) = 1$.

How do I find if $ZN^*$ is closed under addition?

I believe $QR \times QR$ gives a $QR$. Is this correct? What about $QR \times QNR$ and vice versa? Any help or pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: For the first question: what is $1 + 1 + \cdots 1$ ($p$ times). Second question: If a QR times a QNR gave you a QR, what would that imply? QNR times QNR is a bit more interesting...

Comment: QR times QR gives me a QR. Are you saying that I assume QR times QNR gives me a QR and think on those lines? Thank you